# Can I use tubeless tires on Araya DM-27.5 Black 32 hole Rims?

Tags: wheels, innertube, rims, tubeless

Rookie question, apologies in advance.

I have a Saracen Mantra hardtail with **Araya DM-27.5 Black 32 hole Rims**. I currently have **Schwalbe Rapid Rob tires** on both front and back. The tires are very bad and I am constantly getting punctures.

I'm looking at upgrading the tires to a combination of **Schwalbe Hans Dampf / Magic Mary**. My question is - **Should I upgrade to tubeless tires and if so is it possible with my current rims?**

Note - Currently hitting singletracks, looking to take on some more advanced downhill tracks and bike parks. Currently cant afford a full sus bike so making the most of the hardtail.

Any advice is helpful as my knowledge of bikes is still improving.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search for that rim suggests they aren't marketed as being tubeless ready (normally, this is a point of advertisement for a manufacturer). So, you're stuck with running tubes unless you try a [Stan's no-tube kit](http://www.notubes.com/Stans-Tubeless-Kits-C12.aspx) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCun_ZXTPog); or similar) or  [ghetto tubeless](http://www.mtbtechniques.co.uk/MaintananceGhetto.html) (or the [alternative method](https://www.singletracks.com/blog/mtb-repair/tech-how-to-ghetto-tubeless-for-mountain-bikes/)), but this is highly YMMV/at your own risk, and highly dependent on your rim+tire combo (not all rims and tires will work). Or get wheels which are tubeless compatible. Tubeless isn't cheap, but the advantages/disadvantages have been extolled extensively elsewhere on this SE and on the internet.

As for punctures, you can make sure your tires are properly inflated, buy thicker/tougher inner tubes (thin tubes you buy may be under 1 mm thick; thicker tubes may be 4 mm or more, for thorn-proof tubes), run a sealant like Slime, and pick a tougher tire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did google pre to posting the question, however, I couldn't find much on it. 

I'll check out your links and see if any of your suggestions fit the bill. 

Thanks again.